# How can I share an object between my modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

So I have a helper module H, which I `require` from my main script M:

M.js:

```
var o = {foo: 'bar'};
require('H.js').doFunc();
```

H.js:

```
module.exports = {doFunc: function(){ /* how can I set X to o.foo in M's scope? */ return X; }};
```

Thus one can expose things in this direction. What can I do to share things back the other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M.js

```
var o = {foo: 'bar'};
require('H.js')(o);
```

H.js

```
module.exports = function (o) {
   console.log(o);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't quite do it the way you intend because node's architecture creates separate, individual global objects per module. However, you can get something similar using the mechanics of how `this` works in javascript.

In plain js, given:

```
function doFunc () {
    return this.foo;
}

var o = {foo:'bar'};
```

You can do:

```
o.dofunc = doFunc;
o.doFunc(); // returns 'bar'
```

Alternatively:

```
doFunc.call(o); // also returns 'bar'
```

---

So, applying this technique to modules:

In H.js:

```
module.exports.doFunc = function () {return this.foo}
```

In M.js:

```
var o = {
    foo: 'bar',
    dofunc : require('H.js').doFunc
};
o.dofunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

M:

```
o = {foo: 'bar'};

require('./H.js')(); // 'bar'
```

H:

```
module.exports = o.foo;
```

By not declaring the variable, it gets stored on the global object which is shared.